# ImageMagick: How to process multiple analysis with format+info in a single execution of convert?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I analyze the four 1px borders (edges) of an image using something like this:

```
convert IMAGE.jpg +repage -crop x1\!+0+0 -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]\n" info:-
convert IMAGE.jpg +repage -crop x1\!+0+%[fx:h-1] -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]\n" info:-
convert IMAGE.jpg +repage -crop 1\!x+0+0 -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]\n" info:-
convert IMAGE.jpg +repage -crop 1\!x+%[fx:w-1]+0 -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]\n" info:-
```

This gives me the standard deviation of all edges (top, bottom, left, right) so if most of them are 0 I know there is probably a main background/border color.

This is nice but is also poorly optimized because convert has to read the file 4 times. How can I make it print all of these in a single execution?

Additionally, is there a way to know the "average" color of these edges? e.g. if the image is 100x100 and the 100x1 area of top border has 50 pixels black and 50 white I get  "128.128.128,255" next to the standard deviation for that edge.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in a bit of a rush and have not checked this, but you can save the image in a MPR - **Magick Persistant Register** which is a named lump of memory and recall it like this:

```
magick start.png -write MPR:orig -delete 0 -format "%[fx:standard_deviation]\n" \
   \( MPR:orig -crop x1\!+0+0          -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop x1\!+0+%[fx:h-1]  -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop 1\!x+0+0          -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop 1\!x+%[fx:w-1]+0  -write info: -delete 0 \) null:
```

This might do your mean calculation too:

```
magick start.png -write MPR:orig -delete 0 \
   \( MPR:orig -crop x1\!+0+0          -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], " -write info: -resize 1x1\! -format "%[mean]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop x1\!+0+%[fx:h-1]  -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], " -write info: -resize 1x1\! -format "%[mean]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop 1\!x+0+0          -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], " -write info: -resize 1x1\! -format "%[mean]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop 1\!x+%[fx:w-1]+0  -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], " -write info: -resize 1x1\! -format "%[mean]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) null:
```

**Sample Output**

```
0, 65535
0, 0
0.290373, 32767.5
0.290373, 32767.5
```

---

Or, final answer:

```
magick start.png -write MPR:orig -delete 0 \
   \( MPR:orig -crop x1\!+0+0          -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], %[fx:mean.r], %[fx:mean.g],%[fx:mean.b]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop x1\!+0+%[fx:h-1]  -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], %[fx:mean.r], %[fx:mean.g],%[fx:mean.b]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop 1\!x+0+0          -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], %[fx:mean.r], %[fx:mean.g],%[fx:mean.b]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) \
   \( MPR:orig -crop 1\!x+%[fx:w-1]+0  -format "%[fx:standard_deviation], %[fx:mean.r], %[fx:mean.g],%[fx:mean.b]\n" -write info: -delete 0 \) null:
```

**Sample Output**

```
0, 1, 0,0
0, 0, 0,0
0.290373, 0.5, 0,0
0.290373, 0.5, 0,0
```

Comment: Yes, I was coming to that between cooking supper and stuff! Glad you worked out how to put it all together!